# Incorrect display of month days in AnyTime DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, anytime

I encountered a very strange problem when using the [Any+Time DatePicker library](https://www.ama3.com/anytime/): the days of the month are not true. The screenshot below shows the **November**:

[image: November]

As you can see, 5 November is a Thursday, but 6 November is a Saturday. The same thing happens with other months:

[image: December]

JS code snippet:

```
<script>
    $("#anytime-month-numeric-task-taskDate").AnyTime_picker({
        format: "%d.%m.%Z %H:%i",
        beforeShow: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
            }, 0);
        }
    });
</script>
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete picture, this looks like you have some custom CSS that is impacting the styles (probably the width) of the "empty" cells in the first row of the table. Does the problem go away when you comment out your own stylesheets and only use anytime.css?